# OpenStreetMap doesn't display in RStudio (with R 3.2.1)

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet, rstudio, osmarender

I am using code from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/)

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m
```

A point appears in the middle of the screen, but no map. Then I found package to download, i.e. osmar, and included that, i.e.

```
library(osmar)
```

And map is still not displaying. How to fix?

[image]

## Update

I am able to access openstreetmap.com on my web browser. Javascript is enabled. Some places they mentioned use `setView` to display openstreetmap but when I try, the screen is now blank, no pop-up pointer

```
library(osmar)
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  
  setView(174.768, lat=-36.852, zoom=18)
m
```

Comment: Problems with the internet connection? I cannot reproduce the error (R 3.1.3, Win 8 x64, RStudio 0.99.441, leaflet_1.0.0.9999, digest_0.6.8, htmltools_0.2.6, htmlwidgets_0.5, magrittr_1.5, tools_3.1.3 ).

Comment: @lukeA My internet connection is perfectly fine. I even tried again and bottom right of screen says `Leaflet | OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA`

Comment: @lukeA These packages you listed are also needed? Will install those and try again ....

Comment: @lukeA Still not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, found this and worked very well for me:

```
%>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
```

found it here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187926/leaflet-output-is-grey