# Hover-over scatterplot using R Studio

Tags: r, google-maps, rstudio, ggmap

I have an R program and would like a way to hover over the data point and display information. I've been trying to use leaflet, but it's so complicated. [No matter what I try, OpenStreetMap doesn't load in R Studio.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341780/openstreetmap-doesnt-display-in-rstudio-with-r-3-2-1)

I'm just looking for simple way to allow person to hover over datapoint to see information. This code displays the image below:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

...


# create a new grouping variable

sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets <- ifelse(sep[,8] <= 33, "Less than 33%", ifelse(sep[,8] >= 66, "More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%"))
sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets <- factor(sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets,
                               levels = c("More than 66%", "Between 33% and 66%", "Less than 33%"))


# get the map
bbox <- make_bbox(sep$Longitude, sep$Latitude, f = 1)
map <- get_map(bbox)


# plot the map and use the grouping variable for the fill inside the aes
ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color=sep$Percent_SEP12_Assets ), size=9, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","orange","red"), drop = FALSE)
```

[image: map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has a new [leaflet](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet) package that is totally easy to use and should get you what you need. See my rPubs post where I walk through the steps [here](http://rpubs.com/jtdoud/BaltCrime) and include a demo map.

Comment: I went to the leaflet website and the map never loaded. Wrote separate question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341780/openstreetmap-doesnt-display-in-rstudio-with-r-3-2-1. Will check your website

Comment: Getting error with `data$CrimeDate <- as.Date(data$CrimeDate, "%m/%d/%Y")` says `do not know how to convert 'data$CrimeDate' to class “Date”`. cvs FROM https://github.com/sefakilic/coursera-devdataprod/blob/master/app/BPD_Part_1_Victim_Based_Crime_Data.csv?raw=true