# Map displays in R, but not R Studio

Tags: r, scripting, activex, rstudio

Follow-on to [OpenStreetMap doesn't display in RStudio (with R 3.2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341780/openstreetmap-doesnt-display-in-rstudio-with-r-3-2-1?noredirect=1#comment50667803_31341780)

I lowered the security requirements of my browser, but I can only execute the following script in R 3.2.1, not RStudio

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map
```

Map doesn't appear in R Studio. Are there any settings I need to enable. Please assist .... R Studio is more user-friendly.

## Update

When I run code from personal laptop, map displays perfect .....

Comment: this works fine in RStudio (I run the dailies though) on latest OS X and R 3.2.1 with fresh `leaflet` install.

Comment: @hrbrmstr `dailies`? What's that. I'm on Win 7, 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this probably isn't the answer you were looking for, and I apologize for being off topic but...

Have you tried running NotePad++ into RGUI? You get all the user friendliness of RStudio without all the slowness and random crashes. There is a great blog post on doing this I have included below.

http://blog.tersmitten.nl/editing-and-running-r-scripts-with-notepad.html

Hope this makes your life easier and good luck getting RStudio to run your map.

Comment: I suppose I could try:-)

Comment: Strange, I already had NP++ when I downloaded NPPR and opened it, it seemed to automatically attach itself to Notepad ++. I just opened a new notepad document, set the language to R and pressed F8 any time I wanted to run a script... Is that what you tried? If I've only made your life more complicated I'm very sorry!!

Comment: LOL, Life is never complicated, only a roller-coaster :-) Will try out your link

Comment: @Fanderson This is quite helpful. I have follow-on question if you can answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391487/where-is-quakes-in-leaflet-package

Comment: @SohniMahiwal just saw your follow up, it looks like it got answered though!