# Where is "quakes" in Leaflet package

Tags: r, leaflet

I am following code from [here](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html)

But cannot understand where `quakes` was pulled from

```
data(quakes)

# Show first 20 rows from the `quakes` dataset
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag))
```

When I run the program, it works, but I cannot find the `quakes` file in my computer.

I am trying to emulate this code for my own data.

Please guide.

## Update

Imported my own data, i.e.

```
sep <- read.csv("31R_SEP_assets_csv.csv")

leaflet(data = sep[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, popup = ~as.character(Site))
```

Comment: Try `library(help = "datasets")`.

Comment: ?quakes will tell you what exactly it is specifically quakes {datasets}

Comment: @nrussell Oh ok, now I was able to import my own data, thanks!

Comment: The `quakes` dataset is one of the numerous datasets that are included in `R`.  You can see the available datasets by typing `data()`